# Handling value duplication in joins

Tags: sql, join

When joining multiple tables, even where the data is filtered, it seems to me you run the risk of massive duplication of data returned.

Here's a trivial example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/eda08/3

We can see duplication on the `description` and `type` columns.

This is a trivial example and so it doesn't appear "that" bad. But over many more tables, and larger 1:M tables, the amount of duplication will balloon, **up to the point where data transfer size may become a concern**.

What is the general approach to solving these problems? Use of aggregations? Separate queries?

**Voted to close: on second thoughts, I think I'm looking for a magical answer that doesn't exist. The relational model is the relational model and a join is going to produce duplicate values with 1:N relationships.**

Comment: When you join tables together you may denormalize the data.  The answer to your question depends on what exact output you want.

Comment: In your example each record is unique (when you consider all the fields). As  Tim Biegeleisen pointed, you need first to know exactly which data you need. Yous still can do a ´select distinct´ to prevent duplicates....if it is pertinent

Comment: Yes, each row is unique. But that doesn't mean the data isn't de-duplicated. Consider an ORM materialising an invoice object from this - it might want to create a `LineItem` which has a `Product` which in turn has a List of `Type`. And yet "ProductA" is returned multiple times, which isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Well the question is quite broad but don't think you should export flat data structure as records are.

You should indeed serialize them into formats such as `JSON` or `XML`

I don't know if you have to do it directly in SQL but if you can start from Java or C# entities, it should be piece of cake.

Comment: I think I'm searching for a magical answer that doesn't exist tbh. The question is purely about the use of SQL.

Comment: @DanGravell Yes, indeed. You can export your data separately (by table, to keep normalization) or you may try to create stored procedures that will export data to those formats but I don't think it would be worth it.